# Need some help to understand idea of writing complex query in rails active record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, join

I need guidance to understand logic of writing complex queries in rails.

I have three models

```
Business

  has_many :customers
  has_many :transactions

Customer
  has_many :transactions
  belongs_to :business

Transaction
  belongs_to :businesss
  belongs_to :customer
//transaction model has a attribute amount which tells how much amount has been spent in this particular transaction.
```

---

[image]

Now I need to implement filter like this. I am posting screenshot cause that will be easy to understand.

**Edit**

Every Transaction means a visit. Total spent means total amount spent.

Comment: What table holds data about customer visits? Or does transaction mean a visit?

Comment: @forker Yupp every transactions means a visit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt there is a graceful one-query solution that will feet capabilities of AR. But even if there is one, for the sake of performance you'll have to create a material view or aggregate table for total spent ranking values. So assuming you have material view `total_spent_ranking(customer_id, rank)` you could do the usual AR querying:
(Just a sketch.)

```
Customer.joins(:transaction, :total_spent_ranking).select('customer.id').group_by('customer.id').having('total_spent_ranking.rank > 15 and count(distinct transaction.id) > 10')
```